# How to specify external dependencies an autofac module needs

Tags: autofac

We use autofac modules (usually on assembly level) to register types contained in the the given assembly.
Quite often an assembly has some kind of dependency on code (interfaces) which is provided by other assemblies.
These 'external' dependencies are registered by other modules of other assemblies, so everything is fine.

The problem is: it's not at all obvious which external dependencies a module / assembly has, so anyone using that module needs to scan the code for types which are required but not registered by the module.
We 'only' (some exceptions, but not relevant here) use lambda registrations, so at least we only need to look at the autofac modules, but still, I'm looking for a way to *declare* the dependencies which need to be provided by anyone using the module.

In the end the problem is not specific to autofac, but I was wondering if my fellow autofac users had any best practices or tips on declaring external dependencies and making sure they are being provided?

Answer (score 1):

There is no facility Autofac provides for this out of the box and nothing planned.

You could do something custom and create an attribute to mark up the module, but that'd be custom to your implementation.

```cs
[RequiresService(typeof(IEmailSender))]
[RequiresService(typeof(IOrderHandler))]
public class MyModule : Module
{
  // ...
}
```

But a full-blown feature like this has some logical challenges and unwritten additional goals, which is why having something automated to handle it is likely not something Autofac would ever provide.

First, people modifying the module need to remember to both modify the list of registrations being done *and* the set of attributes. On a small team one might be able to maintain that sort of discipline, but on larger teams with varying skill sets the two things are likely to get out of alignment pretty quickly.

Second, while *you're* only using lambdas (which, I'm guessing, have the `new` for each thing built in), that's not really the most common usage pattern. That would mean the person modifying the underlying component classes would need to know both which module(s) the component is getting registered in and modify the types. That couples the underlying components to the module doing the DI registration.

Third, also related to lambdas, this totally wouldn't work with assembly scanning or bulk registration of open generics. Generics in general would be a big problem here because you could have a generic constructor argument so your attribute system would need to account for that, along (possibly) with generic constraints.

Fourth, it's unclear how one might express the need for a service if it's consumed via one of the built-in relationships, like `IEnumerable<IService>` rather than just `IService`. Again, less an issue with very-specific-lambda-registrations, falls apart using reflection or scanning or whatever else.

Finally, invariably someone is going to ask for a way to say, "given this set of modules, are all the dependencies satisfied?" That means not only would there need to be some way to interrogate what's *required* but also what the module *provides*, which, again, runs into all the challenges above with figuring out how to keep the attributes lined up with what's in the module, handling scanning, generics, etc.

Anyway, that's a really long explanation of why it's not there out of the box. Sorry for the rambling.

**For your very specific use case, I'd go with attributes** so you can query the requirements via code and make it easy to programmatically report on things as needed. That's totally what attributes are for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.

Comment: I'm aware of the multitude of challenges a technical solution for this problem has, so I understand that there's no built-in mechanism for it.

For our use case, Attributes might actually be a decent solution (of course it means duplication).

Maybe there are some (non-technical) best practices how to handle such dependencies?

Comment: Would it be painful from a documentation perspective to have to visit potentially hundreds of classes just to find out what service dependencies a user must register after loading a module? Wouldn't it be more useful to implement a list of required services within the module itself, keeping it centrally defined?